# HashSet with HashMap is showing wrong values

Tags: java, hashmap, unique, hashset

When I am trying to add `HashMap` in `HashSet` it is showing wrong values.

**CODE**:

```
HashSet<HashMap> arList = new HashSet<HashMap>();
HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
hm.put("name", "Amit");
hm.put("device_id", "192.168.1.100");
hm.put("ip", "192.168.1.100");
System.out.println("hm:"+hm);
arList.add(hm);
//add again
arList.add(hm);

hm.put("name", "Mani");
hm.put("device_id", "192.168.1.102");
hm.put("ip", "192.168.1.102");
arList.add(hm);

System.out.println("hm:"+hm);
System.out.println("arList: " + arList);
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
hm:{name=Amit, device_id=192.168.1.100, ip=192.168.1.100}
hm:{name=Mani, device_id=192.168.1.102, ip=192.168.1.102}
arList: [{name=Mani, device_id=192.168.1.102, ip=192.168.1.102}, {name=Mani, device_id=192.168.1.102, ip=192.168.1.102}]
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**:

```
hm:{name=Amit, device_id=192.168.1.100, ip=192.168.1.100}
hm:{name=Mani, device_id=192.168.1.102, ip=192.168.1.102}
arList: [{name=Amit, device_id=192.168.1.100, ip=192.168.1.100}, {name=Mani, device_id=192.168.1.102, ip=192.168.1.102}]
```

Comment: When you add a reference to a collection, only that reference is added. It doesn't add a copy of the object referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `hm` variable points to one (1) `HashMap` instance that is subsequently added to the `HashSet` twice (or even three times, with your `// add again` block). The `HashMap` instance will contain the values that have been put last, and the set will contain two (or three) references to the same map.

Create two separate `HashMap` instances to make it work correctly:

```
HashSet<HashMap> hs = new HashSet<HashMap>();
HashMap<String, String> hm1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
hm1.put("name", "Amit");
hm1.put("device_id", "192.168.1.100");
hm1.put("ip", "192.168.1.100");

hs.add(hm1);

HashMap<String, String> hm2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
hm2.put("name", "Mani");
hm2.put("device_id", "192.168.1.102");
hm2.put("ip", "192.168.1.102");

hs.add(hm2);
```